# In-place quicksort - python

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement quicksort in python in-place. I followed the pseudocode from the wikipedia article here, but this is not producing a sorted list. Does anything seem glaringly incorrect?

```
# Perform QuickSort in place
def partition(arr,low,high):
    pivotIndex = random.randint(0,high)
    pivotValue = arr[pivotIndex]

    currentIndex = low

    t = arr[high]
    arr[high] = pivotValue
    arr[pivotIndex] = t

    for i in range(low,high-1):
        if arr[i] < pivotValue:
            t = arr[i]
            arr[i] = arr[currentIndex]
            arr[currentIndex] = t
            currentIndex += 1
    t = arr[currentIndex]
    arr[currentIndex] = arr[high]
    arr[high] = t
    return currentIndex

def quickSort(arr,low,high):
    # pick partition
    if low < high:
        part = partition(arr,low,high)
        quickSort(arr,low,part-1)
        quickSort(arr,part+1,high)

arr = [1,3,6,7,9,10]
quickSort(arr,0,len(arr)-1)
print arr
```

Comment: "this is not producing a sorted list" -- what is it producing instead? What is the *actual problem*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the first line of the `partition` function is clearly wrong:

```
pivotIndex = random.randint(0, high)
```

This should obviously be `low` instead of `0`.

Your `range` values might be off... I don't think you need to subtract 1 from `high`.

Answer (score 0):

Also, in Python you don't have to use a temporal variable to do an exchange.

Instead of:

```
t = x
x = y
y = t
```

You can do:

```
x, y = y, x
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to `import random` ? Also, in order to see the difference, your array must be an unsorted one. If the elements are already in the correct order, how can you find the difference?

Also, by listing all the arrays as `arr`, it can get confusing. I noticed that all functions with `arr` in them are using `arr` as the corresponding parameter. Why not do something do distinguish them?